# Concatenating in EL param

Tags: jsp, jstl, el

Using JSP/JSTL, I am iterating over a list of items:

`<c:forEach var="item" items="${list}" varStatus="loop">
</c:forEach>`

Within the loop, I would like to retrieve a parameter based on the loop index. I know that to access a parameter (e.g. named "p"), I would do: `${param.p}` and to access the loop index, I would do: `${loop.index}`

However, how would I combine these to retrieve a parameter (e.g. named "p0", where 0 is the loop index)? I tried the following, but it did not work.

1) `${param['p'+=loop.index]}`
2) `<c:set var="p" value="p${loop.index}"/>
${param.p}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to resolve this by first creating a new variable and then using bracket notation to retrieve the parameter:

`<c:set var="p" value="p${loop.index}"/>
${param[p]}`